# assign a variable to font color in JLabel

Tags: swing, jlabel

I want to change the color of text in the JLabel. For this purpose, I used HTML format but my problem is how can I assign a variable to the font color? Here is a sample code:

```
`      
    ArrayList<Color> myColor=new ArrayList<Color>();
    ...

    for(int i=0;i<myColor.size(); i++){

    myLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);

    myLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    myLabel.setText(String.format("<html>%s<font color=:"myColor.get(i)+">%s</font></html>",   myLabel.getText(),"new text");

  }  `
```

When I want to run this code, the color is considered black for all of text but I want to assign different color to different text in JLabel.
It should be better to mention that  I had some text in that JLabel. Using setForeground commend results in changing the color of other text. I want to change the color of one text while others have remained in their own color and because of that I used HTML format.
Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setForeground()`. This method will set the font color of your label. For example `myLabel.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);` will set the font color to orange.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had some text in that JLabel. Using setForeground commend results in changing the color of other text. I want to change the color of one text while others have remained in their own color

Comment: You could either assign them all to their own JLabel or set colors to a String variable i.e., `String red = "#FF0000";` and then `myLabel.setText(String.format("<html>%s<font color='" + red + "'>",   myLabel.getText(),"new text");`